# Using wildcard in JPA Query in hbm.xml

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I need to perform a freetext search over a street name. The following query works in SQL Developer:

> select id from UM_ADDRESS where CATSEARCH (street, '(asteric)albert
>   street(asteric)', null) > 0)

its equivalent JPA Query

> select id from UM_ADDRESS where CATSEARCH
>   (street,(asteric):p0(asteric), null) > 0

Due to * Hibernate cannot find the parameter. I have to write query in .hbm.xml file. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Please not there is asteric(*) before albertstreet and :p0

Comment: "CATSEARCH" is invalid JPQL (as a quick review of ANY JPQL doc would reveal). LIKE is valid JPQL (as the exact same references would reveal). Similarly "hbm.xml" is not part of JPA. If you want Hibernate specific then please remove the JPA tag

Comment: JPA Queries, which use JPQL (Java Persistence Query Language) are **not the same** as SQL queries. Although JPQL looks like SQL, it has a different syntax and it does not support database-specific functions. Also, `UM_ADDRESS` is the table name, but the Entity class associated with that table may have a different name. As Neil says, you need to read the JPQL documentation.

Comment: Thanks for replies Neil and Duncan. I have removed the JPA tag. any idea how can I add asteric(*) to parameter in .hbm file. I have currently added it via setter in java but ideally I will like to add it in .hbm.xml file.